# Image written through WriteToFile command is missing after app rerun

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, writetofile

I am writing an app which downloads image from my server and stores them locally for offline viewing. The codes I use to store the image locally are shown below. Apart from storing the image, I am also able to read the image from the path (which I stored separately).

However when I re-run my code from Xcode to the iPhone (without uninstalling the app from the phone), the stored image file would be missing. Is this expected? Would I face similar issue when my app has been released on App Store and when the user updates the app? Is there a way to keep the file persistent when I re-run them when I update some codes in Xcode?

```
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];            
        NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file.jpeg",]];

        if (![imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES])
        {
           // Handling when there is an error
           NSLog(@"Failed to store file at path %@",imagePath);
           stored.text = @""; 
        }
        else
        {  // Handling when write is successful
           NSLog(@"Imaged stored path is %@",imagePath);
           stored.text = imagePath;
        }
        [imageView setImage:image];
```

The code to read the image is shown below:

```
        NSString *imagePathToRead = stored.text; 
        NSLog(@"Retrieve image from %@",imagePathToRead);
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePathToRead];

        [imageView setImage:image];
```

Comment: Nslog the image name. If document's image name and your current image name is same, then it should work.

Comment: I have NSLog just now, the path is exactly the same but I no longer able to retrieve the UIImage after I re-run from Xcode.

Comment: Update your question with the code for loading the image when the app is run again (and include the exact code used to determine the image's path).

Comment: I have updated my question with the codes on how I read the image. The codes have no issue as long as it is not re-run from Xcode. Which means after I run them on the Phone, it would be working fine. If I re-run them from Xcode (after I have updated any codes on other places), I no longer able to extract the image from the exact path.

Comment: You don't show where `stored.text` comes from. FYI - NEVER store a full path. Only store a path relative to the Documents folder (or whatever folder you happen to use). Always build the full path from the runtime determination of the Documents folder and appending the relative path.

Comment: You solved my problem! I should not store the full path but should store the relative path instead. I did a minor modification to my code and the image is able to retrieve successfully without any issue after re-running them from Xcode. Can you post your answer below so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer here from rmaddy which solved the issue I was facing. I am posting here so that others can benefit if they are facing similar issue.

### For the storing portion:

The stored.text should never store the full path:

```
      stored.text = imagePath;
```

Instead I should store @"file.jpeg" only.

### For the Read portion:

I should always regenerate the full path below when I wanted to read the path instead of the code below:

```
      NSString *imagePathToRead = stored.text;
```

The corrected codes are:

```
    NSString *imagePathToRead = stored.text; 

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];            
    NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:imagePathToRead]];

    NSLog(@"Retrieve image from %@",imagePath);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

This solved the issue and the image is able to be read even though the app is re-installed through Xcode.